# Аналог функции foreach для javascript

Tags: javascript

Или по-другому как перебрать все элементы массива в Javascript?

Что-то вроде `foreach(array as value)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript
Если вкратце - то либо применять for(i=0;i<arr.lenght;i++), либо for с hasOwnProperty

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов, в зависимости от ваших задач.

Начнём с простого:

```
var a = ["a", "b", "c"];
a.forEach(function(entry) {
    console.log(entry);
});
```

Немного более старомодный вариант:

```
var index;
var a = ["a", "b", "c"];
for (index = 0; index < a.length; ++index) {
    console.log(a[index]);
}
```

Кроме того, есть собственно `for-in`. Может использоваться, например, для разреженных (sparsed) массивов:

Примитивный, но не совсем верный вариант:

```
for (var key in data) {
  key;//ключ
  data[key];//значение
}
```

Более правильно:

```
var key;
var a = [];
a[0] = "a";
a[10] = "b";
a[10000] = "c";
for (key in a) {
    if (a.hasOwnProperty(key)  &&
        /^0$|^[1-9]\d*$/.test(key) &&
        key <= 4294967294
        ) {
        console.log(a[key]);
    }
}
```

В EcmaScript6 в виде предложения (draft) добавлена ещё конструкция *for-of*:

```
var val;
var a = ["a", "b", "c"];
for (val of a) {
    console.log(val);
}
```

Собственно, по большому счёту, *for-of* это просто правильный *for-in*, не требующий дополнительных проверок как в примере выше. Принципиальные же отличия в деталях можно узнать из [предложения](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aiterators) (англ.).

Подробнее:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript (англ.) — очень подробный ответ на вопрос с детальным рассмотрением всех возможных вариантов
- http://habrahabr.ru/post/247857/ (рус.) — дословный перевод вышеназванного ответа на русский язык

Comment: Еще for-of стоит добавить.

Comment: @uhbif19: Полностью согласен и поддерживаю. Добавлено.

Answer (score 0):

В стандартном JavaScript у массивов есть метод [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].forEach(function(value, index) {
    console.log('a[' + index + '] = ' + value);
});
```

Получаем:

```
a[0] = a
a[1] = b
a[2] = c
```

Не стоит путать с конструкцией `for (key in object)`. Такая конструкция перебирает *свойства объекта*, а не элементы массива. Хотя элементы массива считаются его свойствами, вы получите не только их, и вам придётся фильтровать свойства при помощи `hasOwnProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
    console.log(array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать функцию `$.each` https://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score -1):

посмотрите реализацию [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> #### Синтаксис
>
> ```
> arr.forEach(callback[, thisArg])
> ```
>
> #### Параметры
>
> **callback**   Функция, создающая элемент нового массива, принимает три аргумента:
>
> - **currentValue**     Текущий обрабатываемый элемент в массиве.
> - **index**     Индекс текущего обрабатываемого элемента в массиве.
> - **array**     Массив, по которому осуществляется проход.
>
> **thisArg**   Необязательный параметр. Значение, используемое в качестве this при вызове функции callback.
>
> Следующий код выводит каждый элемент массива на новой строке журнала:
>
> ```
> function logArrayElements(element, index, array) {
>   console.log('a[' + index + '] = ' + element);
> }
>
> // Обратите внимание на пропуск по индексу 2, там нет элемента, поэтому он не посещается
> [2, 5, , 9].forEach(logArrayElements);
> // логи:
> // a[0] = 2
> // a[1] = 5
> // a[3] = 9
> ```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (var i = 0; i <= myArray.length; i++) { /*тут делаем что нужно с myArray[i]*/ }
```